# Ecto dynamic query params in phoenixframework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm new to Elixir and Phoenix framework. How can I dynamically add parameter to ecto query ? For example:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  departments = Repo.all(Department)
  render(conn, "index.json", data: departments)
end
```

Is it possible to use the _params in Ecto query ? Something like:

```
Repo.get_by(Department, _params)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ["bindingless queries"](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/b5eeb7b80c2f16c2ba74c357b0881049b385a663/lib/ecto/query.ex#L166-L197) for this, but there's a problem. Ecto expects the column names to be atoms and the argument to be a keyword list. The latter is easy, but [converting arbitrary user input into atoms may result in the Erlang VM crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34446221/320615). Here's a safe way to do this using a whitelist of column names:

```
# user input
params = %{"first_name" => "John", "last_name" => "Smith", "age" => 28}
filtered_params =
  params
  |> Map.take(~w(first_name last_name age))
  |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)

from(MyApp.Person, where: ^filtered_params)
|> MyApp.Repo.all
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[debug] SELECT p0."id", p0."first_name", p0."last_name", p0."age", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "people" AS p0 WHERE (((p0."age" = ?) AND (p0."first_name" = ?)) AND (p0."last_name" = ?)) [28, "John", "Smith"] OK query=6.5ms queue=14.8ms
[%MyApp.Person{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, age: 28,
  first_name: "John", id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-11T16:01:49Z>,
  last_name: "Smith", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-11T16:01:49Z>}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get stuff dynamically ofcourse, [Repo.get_by](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:get_by/3) in the second argument expects `Keyword.t | Map.t`, either a keyword or a map. You can set it directly from params into a Map or keyword, and pass that into the query. 
Example

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  query_conditions = [id: params["id"], name: params["department_name"] ]
  departments = Repo.get_by(Department, query_conditions)
  render(conn, "index.json", data: departments)
end
```

As @Dogbert stated in the comments that `get_by` will get you 0 or 1 result, more results will raise an error. I only used it because you used `get_by` in the question.

Comment: Note that `Repo.get_by` is only used to fetch 0 or 1 result(s). If the query returns more than 1 results, it raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but one can also make use of `Ecto.Changeset.cast`, and also benefit of its validation. For example, to select all:

```
with %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true} = changeset <- Ecto.Changeset.cast(%Department{}, params, [:department_name]) do
  clauses = Enum.to_list(changeset.changes)

  query =
    from e in Department,
      where: ^clauses,
      order_by: [desc: e.inserted_at]

  {:ok, Repo.all(query)}
else
  changeset -> {:error, changeset}
end
```