# How to use a variable to refer to a key of a struct?

Tags: elixir

How can I use a variable to access a field of a struct:

```
  var1 = "key1"
  struct1 = %MyStruct{key1: "fdsfd", key2: 33}

  val1 = struct1[:????] # how to use var1 for "key1"?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `String.to_existing_atom/1` and `Map.get/2` (as structs are actually maps):

```
iex(1)> defmodule MyStruct do
...(1)>   defstruct [:key1, :key2]
...(1)> end
iex(2)> var1 = "key1"
"key1"
iex(3)> struct1 = %MyStruct{key1: "fdsfd", key2: 33}
%MyStruct{key1: "fdsfd", key2: 33}
iex(4)> val1 = Map.get(struct1, String.to_existing_atom(var1))
"fdsfd"
```

The `[:key]` syntax will not work with structs by default as it uses the [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) protocol which has to be implemented by the user for each struct.

`String.to_existing_atom/1` will throw an error if the atom does not already exist but is safer to use than converting arbitrary input to atom and it will definitely exist if you have a struct with that key already defined. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446221/atom-keys-vs-string-keys-in-phoenix) for more details.

Comment: is it necessary to convert var1 to an atom?

Comment: You could iterate through all the fields of the struct, convert the keys to string, and compare those, but it would be much slower. Something like: `struct1 |> Map.from_struct |> Enum.find(fn {key, _} -> Atom.to_string(key) == var1 end)`.

Comment: but isn't an atom being a key of a struct synonim to a string?

Comment: Atoms and strings are different. A struct can only have atom keys. A map can have any term as key, so you could have a map `%{:a => 1, "a" => 2}`. To Elixir, `:a` and `"a"` look nothing alike.

Answer (score 4):

Besides `Map.get/2`, you can pattern match to get the value, or implement the Access behaviour on your struct, so you can use `struct1[var1]` as you tried.

(Turn your `var1 = "key1"` into an atom with `String.to_existing_atom/1` as suggested.)

Given a `struct1 = %MyStruct{key1: "fdsfd", key2: 33}`

Pattern matching:

```
iex> %{^var1 => value} = struct1
iex> value
"fdsfd"
```

Access behaviour:

```
defmodule MyStruct do
  defstruct key1: nil, key2: nil

  def fetch(my_struct, key) do
    {:ok, Map.get(my_struct, key)}
  end
end

iex> my_struct[var1]
"fdsfd"
```

Note that I didn't implement the full Access behaviour. See [the docs on Access callbacks](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#callbacks) for more.

Comment: Just to comment on the string vs atom thing again: you could implement `fetch(my_struct, key) when is_binary(key), do: fetch(my_struct, String.to_existing_atom(key))`, if you wanted to access struct fields with strings, with the Access behaviour. I would recommend against it, though. It obscures your actual data, and could lead you to think you have string keys in a different context.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Elixir 1.3 or later, you can use the `Access.key!` with `get_in` on any struct:

```
var1 = "key1"
struct1 = %MyStruct{key1: "fdsfd", key2: 33}

val1 = get_in struct1, [Access.key!(String.to_existing_atom(var1))]
```

Prior to Elixir 1.3, it wasn't possible to use `get_in/3` (where the lookup path is variable), and you could only use `get_in/2` like `val1 = get_in struct1.var1`. `Access.key!` has the benefit of either working or raising `KeyError`.